# usermod error: usermod: user '1000' does not exist

Tags: usb, permissions, uid

I want to allow a user to access the USB port.

I am following these instructions:
https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_wizard2/

After the installation of the software, I have to add the account id to the dialout group in order to access the USB port by using this command:

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout <your_account_id>
```

Where `<your_account_id>` is the my User ID.

I got the UserID with  `echo $UID`. The result is 1000.
So the final command would be `sudo usermod -aG dialout 1000`.

However, when I type this, I get `usermod: user '1000' does not exist`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Try the username instead of the UID.

Comment: I have already done it (just restared my computer and this works)! Thank you!

Comment: I have no problem if you answer formally. I will mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `usermod` command requires the **username** instead of the numeric user ID.
The terms *account id* and *your actual user id* in the linked instructions are misleading.